# linking to musl with other headers from /usr/include

Tags: c, include-path, standard-library, musl

I am trying to compile a program with x11 and use musl for the c library. I still have glibc on my system. Musl is located at `/usr/local/musl/include` The glib headers are still in `/usr/include`

When I muild with

```
musl-gcc test.c
```

I get `fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: no such file or directory`

If I try

```
musl-gcc test.c -I/usr/include
```

It includes the glib headers instead of the musl headers and throws a bunch of errors.

If I try

```
musl-gcc test.c -I/usr/local/musl/include -I/usr/include
```

It still includes the headers from glib in /usr/include

How do I make musl-gcc use the musl headers but still include other files from /usr/include?

Comment: Symlinking /usr/include/X11 to /usr/local/musl/include/X11 seems working, but I have no success with symlinking libX11.so to /usr/local/musl/lib. If you on gcc 6, use "-mmusl" option.

Comment: for linux headers just make symlinks into your musl tree.  for Xlib, you'll need to rebuild Xlib (and its prerequisites) against musl and specify /usr/local/musl as your prefix

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @technosaurus from comments. You should add symlinks.

For example, I needed to use linux header `linux/userfaultfd.h` while compiling with `musl-gcc`.
Just make symlinks to include folder(in my case `/usr/include/linux`) and put them into default header-path of musl:

```
pushd /usr/local/musl/include
sudo cp -rs /usr/include/linux/ linux/ # now can #include<linux/...>
```

Note that most probably it won't be enough since included headers may also use `#include <another-path/...>`. You'll notice it in compiler error. Symlink all such `another-path`'s and you are done.

As in my case I needed additionally to symlink those paths:

```
sudo cp -rs /usr/include/asm/ asm/ # now can #include<asm/...>
sudo cp -rs /usr/include/asm-generic/ asm-generic/ # now can #include<asm-generic/...>
```